# Windows Server 2003 VHD - Evaluation expired message on a fresh installation

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-server-2003, vhd

I'm running into a strange issue with Windows Server 2003 VHD.
I downloaded and installed the VHD on my work machine.

After bringing up the Virtual PC instance, I saw the message "30 day evaluation started".

But, within few mins, I saw a dialog:

"The evaluation period for this installation of Windows has expired. The system will shutdown in 1 hour".

Any idea what could be going on? I'm installing this VM on a brand new machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the VM was already created, and you've simply copied it to a new machine, it's likely to still be counting down on it's 30 day activation limit.

You can either attempt to do a rearm of the trial period (not sure if this works in Server 2003). Follow the guide here for (Windows 7):
http://windowssecrets.com/2009/08/20/01-Use-any-version-of-Windows-7-free-for-120-days

OR

An alternate work-around for this could be to disable the Time Synchronization between the virtual machine and the host machine. This way it can remain at a valid date inside the 30 day limit:
http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/11/28/disabling-time-synchronization-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx